# Using EXSLT in Xalan

Tags: java, xslt, wildfly-8, exslt

i use Xalan as XLST-Processor inside the application server wildfly. Everything works fine so far, but when I try to use date and time functions from exlst, i got NoClassDefFoundError and I don't know why.

The definition is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:datetime="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" version="1.0"">
```

When I try to use the year-function `datetime:year` i got the error. Any Ideas why the class can not be found? 
Thank you!

Comment: I can use e.g. `<test processor="{system-property('xsl:vendor')}" function-available="{function-available('datetime:year')}" result="{datetime:year()}"/>` fine with the Xalan version in oXygen 19, gives `<test xmlns:datetime="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" result="2017" function-available="true" processor="Apache Software Foundation"/>`. No idea what wildfly uses and how it configures Xalan, what do you get for `system-property('xsl:vendor')` in your app? Do you get the same error for any EXSLT function use??

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can use exlst:common without any problem. I will try which value the variable xsl:vendor have and wirte it down here soon.

Comment: I still got NoClassDefFoundError. The first part gives me : <test processor="Apache Software Foundation (Xalan XSLTC)" />

Comment: Xalan has two XSLT processors, an interpreter and a compiler, perhaps the compiler XSLTC does not have such a broad EXSLT support so if you use a local installation of Xalan you can always instantiate the interpreter by using `TransformerFactory tf = new org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl();`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Then i have to include org.apache.xalan and the corresponding serializer, but i can use the date functions! Some other things in my xsl doesn't work anymore but i think i perhaps can rewrite it. it was really a problem of the comiler. Thanks a lot again. Would not be able to solve this problem without your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"">
```

In the docs [here](http://exslt.org/dates-and-times) they, are always using "date" and not "datetime"

Comment: sry, was a copy paste mistake. I edited the question